# Splash-Screen to Login screen transition Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, splash-screen

I am new to Kotlin and I am trying to program a Splash screen which will transition into the Login screen but it doesn't want to go past the Splash screen logo animation. It shows the splash screen and logo but then it is just stuck I won't transition to the login screen. I tried logo.animate and ComponentState but it does nothing. The code down there is the base model without the animation.

SplashScreenActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.projektcan.splash

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ImageView
import com.example.projektcan.R

class SplashScreenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)
        val logo=findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.keyLogo)
        logo.alpha=0F
        logo.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(1F).withEndAction{


        }
    }
}
```

LoginActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.projektcan.login

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.projektcan.R

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    }
}
```

Comment: val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
this is not in your code for better understanding follow this completely
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like you've implemented the animation for your splash screen logo correctly. However, after the animation completes (i.e., withEndAction), you haven't added any code to transition from the SplashScreenActivity to the LoginActivity. This is why your app is stuck on the splash screen.

To transition from the splash screen to the login screen, you can use an Intent. Here's how you can modify your SplashScreenActivity to achieve this:

```
package com.example.projektcan.splash

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.projektcan.R
import com.example.projektcan.login.LoginActivity

class SplashScreenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)
        
        val logo = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.keyLogo)
        logo.alpha = 0F
        logo.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(1F).withEndAction {
            // Transition to LoginActivity
            val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish() // Close the splash screen activity
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, after the logo animation completes, it creates an Intent to start the LoginActivity. You should replace LoginActivity::class.java with the actual class name of your login activity if it's different.

Make sure you have also defined both activities in your AndroidManifest.xml file. Here's an example of how you can define them:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.ProjektCan">

    <activity android:name=".splash.SplashScreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".login.LoginActivity" />

    <!-- ... other activities ... -->

</application>
```

Ensure that both activities are correctly declared in your manifest file, and the app would transition from the splash screen to the login screen as intended.